# Notation predictive posterior distribution and $x^*$, $y^*$

Tags: bayesian, prediction, posterior

I often see the posterior predictive distribution in ML defined as follows:

$$p(y^* \mid x^*, X, Y) = \int p(y^* \mid x^*, \omega)p(\omega, X, Y) d\omega$$

where $\omega$ are all parameters, $x^*$ is a new input point and $X, Y$ is the training dataset.

What confuses me is the lower case $y^*$ and $x^*$, because I am not sure whether it is a random variable and where it comes from.

Without knowing a lot about Bayesian statistics, I would first define the posterior $P(W \mid X, Y)$ (with $W$ being the parameters). Then use the law of total probability to obtain

$$P(Y \mid X) = \int P(Y \mid X, W)P(W)dW$$

Next, when I get a new point $x^*$, I would set $P(Y= y^* \mid X = x^*)$. Are $y^*$ and $x^*$ as random variables necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the notation of the posterior predictive distribution
$$p(y^* \mid x^*, X, Y) = \int p(y^* \mid x^*, \omega)p(\omega, X, Y)\, \text{d}\omega\tag{1}$$
in the question,

0. the posterior density on the parameter vector $\omega$ should be denoted $p(\omega|X,Y)$;
1. $p(\cdot|x^*,x,y)$ is a density function
   $$p(\cdot|x^*,x,y)\,:\ \mathcal Y \longmapsto \mathbb R^*_+\tag{2}$$
   indexed by the triplet $(x^*,x,y)$; it is the conditional density function of a random variable, possibly denoted $Y^*$, given $X^*=x$ and the learning sample $(X,Y)$;
2. $y^*$ is the dummy argument of the density, it could be equally, written $z$, $\zeta$, $\Upsilon$, or even *ygrec*, as well; $y^*$ is preferred for the analogy with the components of the learning set $Y$ but it is *not* a random variable by default, even though the function $p$ in (2) could be applied to a random variable;
3. $\omega$ is the vector of parameters indexing the conditional sampling probability density $p(\cdot \mid x^*, \omega)$; while $\omega$ is a random variable in the Bayesian framework, with prior density $q(\omega|X)$ say, it is *not* denoted by a capital letter, like $\Omega$ or $W$. The reason is that (i) this could prove confusing, since $\Omega$ [capital Greek letter] is also traditionally the parameter space *and* the underlying Borel space of measurable sets, while (ii) Bayesian inference returns the posterior distribution and computes summaries of that distribution, like posterior moments or quantiles. Writing$$\int p(y^* \mid x^*, W)p(W, X, Y)\, \text{d}\tag{3}W$$is unusual if formally correct because the notation $W$ indicates a random variable but the integral is computed wrt a dummy variable, rarely denoted by a capital letter (and (3) is not a random quantity);
4. $(X,Y)$ is the training dataset and the capitals are intended for vectors and matrices rather than for random variables, and furthermore $Y$ is actually a realisation of a random vector, thus *not* a random variable (and starting from the model, *everything* is conditional on $X$);
5. the expression $P(Y=y^*|X=x^*)$ is incorrect because $Y$ and $y^*$ (as well as $X$ and $x^*$) are objects of different dimensions. For instance $Y$ is made of $n$ replications $y_i$'s, of the same dimension as $y^*$. Furthermore, if $Y^*$ is a continuous variable, $$P(Y^*=y^*|X^*=x^*,X,Y)=0$$ In learning terms, $(X,Y)$ is the learning set, $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ being the *predictors* and $Y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ the *outcomes*.

Answer (score 1):

What you defined in $P(Y|X)=\int P(Y|X,\omega)P(\omega)d\omega$ is the *prior predictive function*, which is generally used to check if the prior distribution for $\omega$ is reasonable. Notice that the distribution of $\omega$ that appears in this formula is the prior $P(\omega)$, not the posterior $P(\omega|X,Y)$.

Now, we can define $x^*, y^*$ as new random variables such that:

$$y^*|\omega,x^*\sim Y_i|\omega,X_i$$

That is, the new data will follow the same conditional distribution as the training data. Why do we create a new random variable if it has the same distribution as $Y$? Because, as good Bayesians, we want to *condition on $Y$*. It wouldn't make much sense to condition $Y$ on itself, as it would result in a singular distribution. Also, $Y$ is usually taken to be a *vector* containing all the outputs of the training dataset.

Now, the random variable $y^*$ depends only on $x^*$ and $\omega$, and $\omega$ depends on $X$ and $Y$. Using this (in)dependence structure and the total probability law, we have:

$$\begin{align}
P(y^*|x^*,X,Y)&=\int P(y^*,\omega|x^*,X,Y)d\omega\\
&=\int P(y^*|x^*,\omega)P(\omega|X,Y)
\end{align}$$

Which is the posterior predictive distribution.